# Using Google-Account to log into Alfresco

Tags: single-sign-on, alfresco, saml, google-authentication, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to log in to the Alfresco Community Edition using a Google account and using SSO?
How to configure this connection correctly using WSO2 Identity Server?

Comment: have you found the solution? can you share?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation about SAML support on the Alfresco Documentation site: https://docs.alfresco.com/saml/concepts/saml-config-overview.html